# MediaManager.Forms UWP, Invalid path error playing local video

Tags: url, xamarin.forms, uwp, path, visual-studio-2019

I'm a beginner to Xamarin.Forms and UWP. I'm trying to play a local *.mp4 file (Assets\Videos\myvideo.mp4) with Plugin.MediaManager.Forms (v1.0.7) >  UWP(v6.2.9) project > Xamarin.Forms(v4.8.0.18) solution. but an error occurrs, says "The specified path is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700A1)". would you help me?

*There is **no problem** with **web URLs**, just it's for local paths.

I've tried these URLs but none of them works.
c#:

```
Url = "file:///Assets/Videos/myvideo.mp4"
Url = "Assets/Videos/myvideo.mp4"
Url = "ms-appx:///Assets/Videos/myvideo.mp4"
```

Xml Code:

```
<mm:VideoView VideoAspect="AspectFit"  Source="{Binding Url}" AutoPlay="True"  ShowControls="True" />
```

myvideo path at solution explorer:"**mysolution\myproject.uwp\Assets\Videos\myvideo.mp4**" and build action is "**Content**".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Xamarin UWP platform, we suggest you use [`Xamarin.Forms MediaElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/mediaelement) to implement cross-platform media play.

And if you want to play uwp local video file where in the assets folder, you could use the following code.

```
<MediaElement Source="ms-appx:///XamarinForms101UsingEmbeddedImages.mp4"
          ShowsPlaybackControls="True" />
```

For more info please refer this [part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/mediaelement#play-local-media).

Comment: Thanks, Resolved with Octane.Xam.Mediaplayer and your Link. Right URI Scheme for UWP : "ms-appx:///Assets/"